# Change scrpage-scrlayer heading

Tags: scrlayer-scrpage, header

I set the header up to display the current chapter on the top right and this works throughout the whole document (short version below). However, at the same page as showed below, the previous heading is carried over to the next page.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper, bibliography=totoc, parskip=half, BCOR=12mm, captions=tableheading, openany, numbers=noenddot, headinclude]{scrbook}

\usepackage[left=27.5mm,right=16mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}

\usepackage[headsepline=0.4pt, plainheadsepline,]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearscrheadfoot                                                   
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalcolor}
\automark*{chapter}
\ihead*{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}


\begin{document}


\pagenumbering{roman}


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhaltsverzeichnis}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}


\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Einleitung}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\chapter*` does not set marks for the header, so `\headmark` shows still the previous chapter heading. With a KOMA-Script class you could use `\addchap` to get an unnumbered chapter title with header and TOC entry. But you are using `scrbook` and roman page numbers in frontmatter and arabic page numbers in mainmatter. So I would suggest to use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`. Then you can use `\chapter{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}`, because chapters in frontmatter are not numbered automatically.

```latex
\documentclass[oneside,bibliography=totoc, parskip=half, BCOR=12mm, captions=tableheading, numbers=noenddot, headinclude]{scrbook}

\usepackage[left=27.5mm,right=16mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,main=ngerman]{babel}% <- changed, assuming your main language is German

\usepackage[headsepline, plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles% <- changed
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalcolor}
\automark{chapter}
\ihead*{\headmark}
\ohead*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Einleitung}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional remarks:
I have removed options `11pt` and `a4paper`. They are default. Option `openany` is not needed for a onesided document. `0.4pt` is the default linewidth for `headsepline`. `\clearscrheadfoot` is deprecated, use `\clearpairofpagestyles` instead.